# Set a timeout limit when reading a file

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a basic script that runs through a file line by line until a time limit is reached. Is there a way to stop the `read -r line` after x timelimit? I tried `-t 10` for a 10 second limit. I also tried a while loop

From the `man read -t` only seems to be relevant for a `timeout` not a time limit

`file.txt` contains over 150000 lines of random characters separated by new lines

code attempt 1:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="./file.txt"
while IFS='' read -r -t 10 line ; do
    echo "$line"
done <"$file" #finished
```

code attempt 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
timelimit=10
file="./file.txt"
while [[ "$timelimit" -gt "0" ]] ; do
    sleep 1
    ((--timelimit))
    while IFS='' read -r line ; do
        echo "$line"
    done <"$file" #finished
done
```

code attempt 1 fails since it has no limiter (just a timeout set)

code attempt 2 fails since it runs the decrement then the next while loop and wont re-enter until it has finished a full loop (15000 lines)

Comment: time limit from what time origin?

Comment: Do you have access to `timeout` command?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am new to bash and don't fully understand your question sorry.

Comment: @Cyrus I just tried timeout and it says it is enabled (just need to supply it with valid argument(s)). I will need to access the $line data it ends on for reading/manipulation after, will a timeout function best work in this situation? Additionally, other things are running before this is called so setting a time to live type function on the entire script may not give me the most accurate results :(

Comment: You could query the time with `date` and compute time differences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this possible solution, using `date +%s`:

```
CURRENT_DATE=$( date +%s )
END_DATE=$(( CURRENT_DATE+10 ))

while [ $CURRENT_DATE -le $END_DATE ];
do
    read -r LINE
    if [ $? -ne 0 ];
    then
        break
        #exit from loop if file is over...
    fi
    CURRENT_DATE=$( date +%s )
    #update CURRENT_DATE...
done
```

The above mentioned command returns the current date value in seconds from [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (January 1st, 1970).

Comment: I couldn't see in this example how it could be possible to read line by line from a flowing log file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in variable `SECONDS` for rough control.

```
SECONDS=0  # reset the counter
file="./file.txt"
while ((SECONDS < 10) && IFS= read -r line ; do
    echo "$line"
done <"$file" #finished
```

Assuming each `read` and the body of the loop doesn't take too long, the loop will exit very close to 10 seconds after it begins.